# KDB domain error when opening a connection to TP log file

Tags: kdb

I created a TP log file using the below code and I see that the file has been created successfully.

```
    tpFileName: `$":sym.", string .z.d-1;
    tpFileName set ();
    upd: insert;
    tpLogPath:.Q.dd[tpDirPath;tpFileName];
```

show tpLogPath gives me `:/path/to/TP/log/file/tpFileName

But when I try to hopen to it, I get 'domain.

```
h: hopen tpLogPath
```

Without opening a connection, I am unable to send data into TP. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your tp log exist already or are you trying to create it from scratch?

Answer (score 2):

But in your example code has an extra `:` in it.
Should look more like:

```
tpDirPath:`:/somewhere/on/your/machine
tpFileName: `$"sym.", string .z.d-1; // I removed : from this
upd: insert;
tpLogPath:.Q.dd[tpDirPath;tpFileName]; //Only first element should be a hsym
tpLogPath set ();
```

If you needed dynamic:

```
tpLogPath:.Q.dd[tpDirPath;{$[":"~first string x;`$1 _ string x;x]}tpFileName];
```

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/replay-log/

Comment: Thank you. I did this already prior to .Q.dd. Here's my code

logFile: `$":sym.", string .z.d-1;
logFile set ()
upd:insert

Comment: Answer updated. You are passing 2 `hsyms` to `.Q.dd`. Only the first should be a `hsym`. You will see your `tpLogPath` has an extra `:` making it a broken path.